# Laravel 4 - Accents for text field not displayed

Tags: php, mysql, character-encoding, laravel, laravel-4

I've got a problem on a laravel 4 project.
My db, tables and fields are in utf8_unicode_ci.
The problem appears only with text fields, it works well with varchar fields

The accents are not shown. 
It's not like it was an encoding problem with "Ã©" instead of "é".

For exemple in the sentence : "Le soleil d'été éclate", i'll got "Le soleil d't clate".

Here's my code.

**app/config/database.php**

```
'driver'    => 'mysql',
...
'charset'   => 'utf8',
'collation' => 'utf8_unicode_ci',
'prefix'    => '',
```

In the view, i use a classic blade echo {{ $myobject->field }}

Any help would be greatly appreciated !

Thanks.

PS : Sorry for my english.

Comment: Look if the text values have the accents on database or if the problem came when you print them on screen.

Comment: @DonnieRock I was about to ask the same! :D